# Como inserir elementos em um vetor R com append?

Tags: r, append

> Estou tentando adicionar elementos a um vetor em R; porém ele dá o
> erro dizendo que o objeto não foi encontrado. Realmente é necessário
> criar um objeto vazio?

---

```
for (i in 1:length(hosts)) {
  n <- nrow(logs_slap[which(logs_slap$host == hosts[i]) ,])
  num_acessos <- append(num_acessos, n)
}
```

Console:
Error in append(num_acessos, n) : object 'num_acessos' not found

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, dê uma olhada [neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) (principalmente no uso da função `dput`) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A resposta à pergunta é sim, é preciso criar um objeto vazio. Mas a melhor forma de fazer o que o código tenta fazer e que conseguiria se o objeto fosse criado fora do ciclo `for` é criar um vetor do mesmo comprimento do `host` e atribuir valores no ciclo.

```
num_acessos <- integer(length(hosts))
for (i in seq_along(hosts)) {
  n <- nrow(logs_slap[which(logs_slap$host == hosts[i]) ,])
  num_acessos[i] <- n
}
```

Desta maneira não se está a tornar o objeto maior de cada vez que lhe é atribuído mais um elemento. Isso obriga o R a chamar as rotinas de gestão de memória e torna o código mais lento.

---

Ainda melhor é criar o vetor `num_acessos` de forma vetorizada. Em uma linha:

```
num_acessos <- as.vector(table(match(logs_slap$host, host)))
```